# Store and Process Messages in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have used ActiveMQ for publishing my message to the consumer so that I can receive the message at consumers end and trigger something.

Now my question is that can ActiveMQ support storing and processing the group of messages? For example:

If a group of messages published at a time I need to get the first two and process. The rest of them should wait in queue. After those two messages have processed I need to get another to process until I processed the picked messages, The rest of the message should wait in queue.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you saying you want to process the messages in a specific order, or that you just don't want to process other messages until you are ready?

Comment: @ErikWilliams I don't want to process other messages until i need another...

Comment: Messages remain in the queue unless you pick them from the queue. I think you need to explain your problem better so we can understand what it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is not possible.Consumer can consume only a single message at a time ,once it has been processed other message is picked up an so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`You need to Subscribe the message after you completed your old process`. `ActiveMQ` will give away the message when you pick it from the queue.